# Getting an errox when opening a textfile

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open a file to edit what's inside with but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/LittleSmashBros/Editeur de niveau.py", line 95, in <module>
    fichier = open("niveau1.txt",)
TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found
```

This is not my first time coding something but I am pretty new to this. My textfile is in the right file, it worked before. It stopped working when I added the function fichier_temp. If you could find what's the problem and explain how to solve it. This is my code, sorry for the variable name, I am French.

```
from tkinter import *
from os import *

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("LittleSmashBros")
fenetre.geometry("1110x720")
bgImage = PhotoImage(file="Greenbg.png")
fond = Canvas(fenetre,width=1110,height=720)
fond.place(x=-2,y=-2)
fond.create_image(0,0,image=bgImage,anchor="nw")
fond.create_rectangle(1080,0,1111,720,fill="black")

#Stocke les images dans des variables
platGauche = PhotoImage(file="platGauche.png")
platMilieu = PhotoImage(file="platMilieu.png")
platDroite = PhotoImage(file="platDroite.png")

#Bouton qui définissent le bloc choisi
typeBloc = "V"
couleurB = "black"
def changeBloc(bloc): typeBloc = bloc
def boutonEnfonce(bouton) :
    bloc1.config(bg=couleurB)
    bloc2.config(bg=couleurB)
    bloc3.config(bg=couleurB)
    bouton.config(bg="white")
bloc1 = Button(fenetre,image=platGauche,height=21,width=21,relief=FLAT,bg=couleurB,command=lambda : [changeBloc("G"),boutonEnfonce(bloc1)])
bloc2 = Button(fenetre,image=platMilieu,height=21,width=21,relief=FLAT,bg=couleurB,command=lambda : [changeBloc("M"),boutonEnfonce(bloc2)])
bloc3 = Button(fenetre,image=platDroite,height=21,width=21,relief=FLAT,bg=couleurB,command=lambda : [changeBloc("D"),boutonEnfonce(bloc3)])
bloc1.place(x=1082,y=10)
bloc2.place(x=1082,y=41)
bloc3.place(x=1082,y=72)

#Prend les coordonnées de la souris et donne sa position sur la grille
def cordsouris(cord):
    global x0,y0
    x0 = cord.x
    y0 = cord.y
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 22
    y1 = 0
    y2 = 22
    testx = False
    testy = False
    colonne = 0
    ligne = 0
    while testx == False:
        if x1 < x0 < x2:
            testx = True
            colonne = colonne + 1
        else:
            colonne = colonne + 1
            x1 = x1+21
            x2 = x2+21
    print(colonne)

    while testy == False:
        if y1 < y0 < y2:
            testy = True
            ligne = ligne + 1
        else:
            ligne = ligne + 1
            y1 = y1+21
            y2 = y2+21
    print(ligne)
    return (colonne,ligne)

#Créé la ligne a remplacer
def remplace_str_index(ligne,place,remplacement):
    texte = fichier.readline(ligne)
    return '%s%s%s'%(texte[:place],remplacement,texte[place+1:])

#Copie l'ancien fichier dans un nouveau avec la modification
def fichier_temp():
    fichier = open("niveau1.txt")
    colonne,ligne = cordsouris()
    with open("temp.txt","w")as temp:
        nb = 0
        for rang in fichier:
            nb = nb+1
            if nb==ligne: text = remplace_str_index(ligne,colonne-1,typeBloc)
            else : text = rang
            temp.write(text)
            print(rang)
            print(text)
    fichier.close()
    os.remove("niveau1.txt")
    os.rename("temp.txt","niveau1.txt")


#Détecte le click et effectue le changement de bloc
fond.bind("<Button 1>",fichier_temp)

#Place l'image en fonction du fichier texte
fichier = open("niveau1.txt",)
x=0
y=0
for rang in fichier:
    for caractere in rang:
        if caractere=="S":
            fond.delete(fond.find_closest(x,y))
        if caractere=="G":
            fond.create_image(x,y,image=platGauche,anchor="nw")
        if caractere=="M":
            fond.create_image(x,y,image=platMilieu,anchor="nw")
        if caractere=="D":
            fond.create_image(x,y,image=platDroite,anchor="nw")
        x = x+21
    x = 0
    y = y+21
fichier.close()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: `open` is not the builtin `open`, right?

Comment: I tried googling and os.open has a second argument called "flags". It's conflicting with the builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why you should never use `from X import *`.

`from os import *` overridden the builtin `open` in Python with `os.open` (which, unlike the builtin `open`, does not have a mode).

Either remove the star import or provide a flag like you have in the other places you used `os.open`.

Comment: Well I wanted to rename and delete some textfile and I saw that i needed to import this library. So do I use the os.open method ?

Comment: @Dave you do not need to use `os.open`. You should  `import os` and then use what ever you need from it (ie `os.rename`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the file open mode

```
open("niveau1.txt", "r")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the real problem, `r` is the default mode and is not a must (unless OP has some code they don't show us, and `open` is not the builtin `open`)

Comment: Problem should be the comma, isn't it ? open("niveau1.txt",)

Comment: No, `open('niveau1.txt', )` is totally valid

Comment: @jgoday Was about to say the same. It's not expecting an argument until you declare one is coming.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock It's not the problem. `open('niveau1.txt', )` actually works

Comment: Well already I tried it and it says that an integer is required

Comment: @Dave, is there some code that you don't show us, and `open` is not the builtin `open`?

Comment: Both @DeepSpace and NoSplitSherlock are right, strange anyway

Comment: He's importing `os *` which also contains `os.open` which is conflicting with the builtin `open`.

Comment: I just edited the question and added the missing part

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
from os import *
```

It also imports `os.open` which now overrides the builting `open`.

If you only import the parts you need from `os` it will work fine.